# Erro do SQL na casting de int para string

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho um método onde preciso retornar o ID (`integer`) de um determinado registro cujo nome passo como parâmetro, porém o Visual Studio aponta o seguinte erro :

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Esse erro ocorre na linha comentada:

```
public int buscarIdPorNome(string nomeSetor) //Busca id do setor pelo nome
    {
        int idSetor = 0;

        con = dal.conectar();//Conectando com o BD - retorna "new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());"
        string cmdText = "SELECT (ID_Setor) FROM dbo.Setor WHERE Nome_STOR = @Nome_STOR"; //Definindo comando
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con); //Adicionando comando

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome_STOR", nomeSetor);

        con.Open();
        idSetor = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //Dando erro

        if (con != null)
        {
            con.Close(); //Fechando conexão
        }

        return idSetor;

    }
```

Já tentei mudar o código que está dando erro, porém não obtive sucesso, continua apontando o mesmo erro. Comando que eu tentei:

```
idSetor = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Lembrando que o objeto `con` é um `SQLConnection` e o método `dal.conectar();` está apenas criando a `StringBuilder`, definindo o servidor e o banco, porém acho que não é relevante para esse erro colocar o código aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há nada de errado com seu código, eu repliquei e funciona normalmente (verifique o print).

Seu problema está na sua Query, já tentou reproduzir sua query no banco ?

```
DECLARE @Nome_STOR varchar(100)
SET @Nome_STOR = 'Nome do Setor'
SELECT (ID_Setor) FROM dbo.Setor WHERE Nome_STOR = @Nome_STOR
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como sugestão utilize a cláusula using no seu SqlConnection:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=CourseDB;server=(local)"))
{
    string nomeSetor = "Thiago";
    string cmdText = "SELECT (Id) FROM dbo.Student WHERE Name = @Nome_STOR"; //Definindo comando
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con); //Adicionando comando

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome_STOR", nomeSetor);

    con.Open();
    idSetor = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //Dando erro
}
```